# Contact lookup option is not displaying any records in lightning custom component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a component which creates quote by fetching information from opportunity.
Here i have lookup to accoutn, contact, opportunity, billto, postto.
Account and opportunity lookup is working fine and showing the records for user to choose, but once user click on primary contact lookup i am not able to see any records.
This is happening only with contact lookups.

[image: ComponentScreen]

**Additional Information:**
We have lookup filter for contact as,
quote->contact->AccountId = Quote->AccountId.

[image: Lookup Filter]

Please let me know where am i going wrong.

Issue is solved by using custom lookup component.
Refer this site which helped me.
https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/

Comment: Do you have contacts in your system matching the look up filter criteria?

Comment: Yes i do have...

Comment: Are you using lightning:recordEditForm in your custom component?

Comment: @maniaccoder yes

Comment: I found the solution for this by creating a custom lookup component.

Comment: There is a known issue for this https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E9xzQAC 
Even I had to create a custom component for this